# Blocking pfsense management access in high-availability setup

Tags: pfsense

I have a pfsense setup in a high-availability configuration. There are about 5 separate networks forwhich I would like to block management access to pfsense. There is a destination rule builtin for each of the interface addresses but this only covers the HA IP and not the addresses for the 2 boxes themselves. What is the best way to setup this rule? The concern with creating an alias is that future networks additions will have their interfaces overlooked from being entered into the alias vs copying a set of rules over.